# Object reference not set to an instance of an object error using a for loop

Tags: c#, .net, object-reference

```
    private void btnAddStudent_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        student[counter] = new Student(txtStudentName.Text, txtStudentSurname.Text,     int.Parse(txtExamMark.Text), counter);
        counter++;

    }

    private void btnAverage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        for (int i = counter; i <= counter; i++)
            MessageBox.Show("" + student[i].Average);
    }
```

My program is giving me the error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I only want the loop to run once to only display the last calculated average. If i do this:
ie: change `int i = counter` to `i = 0`

```
    private void btnAverage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
            MessageBox.Show("" + student[i].Average);
    }
```

Then my program works but it displays the messagebox as many times depending on the amount of students `i` entered, with the last value being the correct average.

I used a class called `Student` to calculate the average. That is not the problem however, because the correct average is being displayed.

What can I do to fix this error?

Comment: Please update your title with your specific problem.. Read [ask]

Comment: What's the full stack trace? *Not* just the message, the entire thing, don't skimp out on the details.

Comment: 1. have you set any breakpoint and get the undefined variable? 2. where `counter` is defined?

Comment: What is your `counter` variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you do not appear to need a loop since `counter` is going from `counter` to `counter`.

Secondly, I suspect you have an out-by-one error.

What happens if you try this?

```
private void btnAverage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (counter > 0)
        MessageBox.Show("" + student[counter-1].Average);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that `student[counter]` is null, while `student[0]` isn't, so I guess that your `counter` is not properly aligned with your `student` array.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
if (student.Length > 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("" + student[student.Length - 1].Average)
}
```

without the loop - that will just show the last average in the array.

Comment: Will crash if `student.Length == 0`

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is because you are trying to access an item in the array/collection that has no instance (Why you receive the error).  Setting counter to 0 works because `student[0]` has an instance of `Student`.

If you want to only get one item, you don't need a loop, you can access `student[i]` directly by passing in the index of the array, i.e. `0`.

```
MessageBox.Show("" + student[0].Average);
```

Comment: If student is a typical .net array or arraylist, the error would be related to an out of bounds index.

Comment: It's rather more likely that the array is declared as rather... large, and that OP is trying to access an existent index, but which isn't assigned yet.

Comment: @J.Steen - yes that's what I tried to explain in my answer.  I have edited to try to clarify this a little further.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I misread. Extraneous information that confused me. =)

Answer (score 0):

A less error-prone approach would be to use a `List<T>` instead of an array:

```
List<Student> students = new List<Student>();
private void btnAddStudent_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    students.Add(Student(txtStudentName.Text, txtStudentSurname.Text,
                 int.Parse(txtExamMark.Text), counter);
    counter++;
}

private void btnAverage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(students.Any())
    {
        MessageBox.Show("" + students.Last().Average);
    }
}
```

Comment: THANKS, but the practical was given to us by our lecturer and a requirement was to write it using an array of objects...